# Build in Visual Studio Team Services: add files after deployment

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-devops

I am publishing the .net code to Azure web app using the build service in Visual Studio Team Services (was Visual Studio Online). I want to add License file to the wwwroot folder in Azure web app after the deployment. Please let me know how can i do this automatically after the deployment in Team Services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use curl to upload the file to your Azure WebSite via following steps:

1. Open Azure Portal and navigate to your Web App.
2. Open the dashboard for your web app and click "Download the publish profile". (There are two publish information included in the profile: MSDeploy and FTP, use FTP credential in following steps).
3. Add a "cURL Upload Files" steps in your build definition.
4. Configure the cURL task with the FTP credentials in the publish profile and the file you want to upload. (When copy the publishURL to cURL task, add an additional "/" at the end of the URL)
5. Save the definition and queue a new build.

The file will be uploaded to your Azure Web App wwwroot folder.